# Nativescript imageSource.fromAsset getImageAsync error

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to upload base64 encoded image picked from the device's gallery.

Basically I select the picture and set it as `source` of an `ImageView`.
Later I upload whatever the `src` of the `ImageView` is.

I'm using `nativescript-imagepicker` for the selection of the image :

```
let context = imagePicker.create({
        mode : "single"
    });
    context.authorize()
        .then(()=>{ return context.present();})
        .then((selection)=>{
            selection.forEach((selected)=>{
                selected.getImage().then((value :ImageSource)=>{
                    imageView.src = value; //here I set the image as source
                })
            })
        });
```

Afterwards in the upload method I try to do the following :
The `fromAsset` method is part of the Nativescript's `ImageSource` module.

```
fromAsset(imageView.src).then(
    (res) => {
    imageSource = res;
    photo.base64 = imageSource.toBase64String('jpg');
    ..
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error); // here I get TypeError.asset.getImageAsync is not a function
})
```

When I use the above method with an image snapped directly from the camera everything goes smoothly, however **if the image is selected** from gallery I get the following error : **TypeError.asset.getImageAsync is not a function**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: update your tns-core-modules and NativeScript CLI

Comment: Also, when working with temp images from Gallery you might want to explicitly save them and then create an imageSource from it https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ImageUpload/blob/master/app/main-page.js#L93-L95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the code in this link and is working perfect! I hope it works https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/issues/62